# Pagination not working on p2 after Woo upgraded to 3.3.3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I upgraded woocommerce from 2.2.8 to 3.3.3 and now the pagination only works on the first page, unless I refresh the page then the pagination appears again.

I've looked through the code but I'm new to woocommerce and tbh haven't a clue where to look/what to try.

If I replace the woocommerce directory with the old one it works again, there are some customisations for woocommerce, notably a 'result-count.php' in the themes child directory:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}
?>
<p class="woocommerce-result-count">
<?php
if ( $total <= $per_page || -1 === $per_page ) {
    /* translators: %d: total results */
    printf( _n( 'Showing the single result', 'Showing all %d results', $total, 'woocommerce' ), $total );
} else {
    $first = ( $per_page * $current ) - $per_page + 1;
    $last  = min( $total, $per_page * $current );
    /* translators: 1: first result 2: last result 3: total results */
    printf( _nx( 'Showing the single result', 'Showing %1$d&ndash;%2$d of %3$d results', $total, 'with first and last result', 'woocommerce' ), $first, $last, $total );
}
?>
```

But I don't know if this is related?

Thank you

Update:
It is something to do with the WOOF plugin and the theme, I turned off 'Try to ajaxify the shop' and the pagination is working again.

https://www.woocommerce-filter.com/pagination-troubles-in-ajax-mode/

Comment: A lot of woocommerce template have been updated in 3.3.x update… To see which ones need to be replaced, you can go in backend **Woocommerce** > **Status** and at the end of the page in **"Templates"** section, you will see which one are obsolete in your active theme Woocommerce folder (and needs to be replaced)…

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the templates highlighted, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with how to plugin is trying to enable AJAX. I use this plugin as well, and it seems to work just fine without enabling "Try to ajaxify the shop". One thing I had to check was to make sure in the widget settings I left all of the options set to "no" as that seemed to mess up the autosubmit feature on the filters otherwise.

Don't know if that solution will work well enough for you, but it worked for me alright.